# java.lang.NumberFormatException while using h:inputText along with f:validateRegex

Tags: validation, jsf, tomcat, numberformatexception

I have an JSF form with only one `<h:inputText>`. 99% of the time it works fine, but sometimes, somehow submitting the form bypasses all the controls and gives the:

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

This is the `<h:inputText>`

```
<h:inputText value="#{controler.bean.id}"
             id="code"
             size="60"
             maxlength="50"
             required="true"
             label="Code"
             autocomplete="off"> 
<f:validateRegex pattern="(^(905|904|918)\d{47}$|^(00030006|00050006|00050070)\d{42}$)"/>
</h:inputText>
```

More info:

- I'm using Tomcat
- The `id` is a Java `Integer`
- The web.xml has no session-timeout (by default using the Tomcat timeout)
- The managed bean is `@RequestScoped`
- The person that uses this page is using a barcode scanner.

Comment: when happens the issue? can you show the java code that trhows this exception? I guess with a simple `try-catch` you can avoid this problem...

Comment: Thats the problem, it happens in the submitting action, I think when JSF starts mapping the form with the bean. I have a custom error page, that says something like "problem has ocurred reload the page" and then all works fine. The problem never happened to me, I only know the issue because of the logs.

Comment: I don't know how the users manage to bypass all the controls, required=true should be enough.

Comment: there is double validation for this stuff... so you should double check value in server-side with `catch(NumberFormatException ex)` ... **problem solved!** If you trust only in client-side validation this errors may happen sometimes, not necessary by users bypass or bad usage, could be simply a connection problem

Comment: or maybe the page loses the session but this page don't need user and password.

Comment: You're missing the point @JordiCastilla : the NFE will be thrown during validation, before it gets to OP's code

Comment: Is the field submitted by ajax? What build of JSF are you using?

Comment: @kolossus is not ajax, the JSF is 2.2.4. The problem was before the f:validateRegex too.

Comment: changed to JSF 2.2.10 and the problem persists